# change wp_nav_menu sub-menu li class

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to convert this html menu as a word-press menu.but problem is.
But i do not how can i change sub-menu anchor class and li class. 
I am unable to replace default word-press sub-menu  items class.

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"> Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="current">
        <a href="#"> Osool <i class="icon-angle-down"></i> </a>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="about.php"> About Us </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Our Team </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Our History </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Our Clients </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Download Profile </a> </li>
             
        </ul>
    </li>      
    <li>
        <a href="#"> Services <i class="icon-angle-down"></i></a>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#"> Data Recovery </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Data Backup </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Data Transfer </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Hard Drive Repairing </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Surveillance Cameras </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Web Hosting &amp; Domains </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Web Designing &amp; Development </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> E-Marketing </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> Accounting System </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#"> ERP Systems</a> </li>
        
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Blogs </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Partners </a> </li>
     
    
    <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please read this one before asking any question here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then try something after that share with your workout and let us know the specific issue if you still don't understand then google first after ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the Walker_Nav_Menu to override. Here is a sample tutorial: http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/wordpress-custom-walker-output-section-of-menu/